# Google Cloud Messaging Authentication Error (401)

Tags: android, python, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using python-gcm for a push notification backend server.

I can successfully send push notifications to my Android application from my local computers. Everything works as expected.

However, when I run it from my server I always get the following error:

```
GCMAuthenticationException: There was an error authenticating the sender account
```

The server is whitelisted (I added the IPv4, IPv6, as well as 0.0.0.0/0 to make sure).
Also the API key is definitely right, I copied my config file.

What else can be the reason it is not working?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem: even just running the suggested test curl command in GCM's Authentication Error description (http://goo.gl/I7Oz2F) works on my local machine, fails on my server.  With 0.0.0.0/0 in the whitelist.

Comment: As python-gcm stopped working completely I tested node-gcm and it seems to work even from my server now. Maybe the library is broken due to changes from Google's side?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the only way I got it to work was to add 0.0.0.0/0 to my whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, as per my comment on the original question, where even just running curl from the command line, as suggested by the [GCM Documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error), gave a different result on my local machine versus on the server, even with 0.0.0.0/0 in the whitelist.

It turned out that my server was (invisibly to me) running curl through IPv6 by default, and so I could solve the problem by either forcing curl to run through IPv4 (with the -4 switch) or adding my server's IPv6 address to the GCM whitelist.  I suspect adding the wildcard IPv6 address would work too, but I did not try that.

In any case, sensibly enough in retrospect, the IPv4 wildcard does not apparently match IPv6 on traffic.